# Swipe animation displays only one page at once

Tags: jquery-mobile

When using swipe to slide pages, e.g.

```
// swipe right event (currentpage is pseudo code)
$("body").pagecontainer("change", "#page" + currentpage - 1, { transition: "slide", reverse: true });


// swipe left event
$("body").pagecontainer("change", "#page" + currentpage + 1, { transition: "slide" });
```

I get this effect: on swipe right, the current page disappears immediately and the previous page slides in from the left. On swipe left, the current page slides out to the left and then the next page appears immediately.

What I want is that the old page slides out and the new page slides in simultaneously, like in Omar's example: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/L297j/

I tried $.mobile.changePage instead of the newer $("body").pagecontainer("change") but that makes no difference. I made sure that the slide target pages do exist ahead of the slide (the pages are created dynamically) and I also added another call to the page constructor before setting up the swipe.

"flip" transition looks perfectly fine in the same place, probably because there are never two pages visible at the same time? I have no clue and I am hoping that someone knows more "slide" pitfalls.

Comment: Do you mean you want to see both pages slide like this image slider. --- http://www.jssor.com/

Comment: make sure that you append new pages before _changing_ pages. Please more relevant code.

Comment: The you need a pagebeforechange event --- jQuery( ".selector" ).on( "pagebeforechange", function( event ) { ... } )

Comment: @Tasos: yes, that is how I want it so slide. About the "pagebeforechange" what should I do inside this event? The swipe event is already bound and the pages are already rendered at this point.

Comment: Could you please post more code of how you inject pages dynamically and bind swipe events?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it took a while to recreate the problem and the fiddle became rather lengthy:

http://jsfiddle.net/timvdh/eFDLr/7/

I am using a static panel in this example:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="select-panel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a" data-bind="jQM: true">
    <div data-role="header" class="ui-header ui-bar-inherit">
        <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Optionen</h1>
        <a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The

```
data-bind="jQM: true"
```

binding essentially executes

```
 $("#select-panel").trigger("create");
```

This has to be done since the static panels (panels outside of pages available for every page) do not get enhanced by jQM otherwise.

However, in this special case everything seems to work fine, but the slide becomes ugly as described in the question.

The simple workaround is the remove

```
data-role="header"
```

from the header. You can try it in the fiddle and the slide will work fine.